# How do I set a button's inner properties in code?

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I have an XAML button like this:

```
<Button x:Name="buttonOK" Content="OK" />
```

I have no XAML styling attached to it and no resource dictionary styling it. No external thing is styling my button and that is fine; that is how I want it.

I want, now, to change the RadiusX and RadiusY of that button in code behind, because I want a button with rounded edges. I know System.Windows.Controls.Button does not have those properties, but I know a WPF rectangle does.

I don't know if this is correct; but the WPF button control is made up of other controls? Right? Like perhaps a rectangle and a text block or label and by setting the Button.Content you're actually changing the button's inner label's content. I'm not sure how naive my thinking is there.

The bottom line is I want to do something like this:

```
buttonOK.InnerRectangle.RadiusX = 5;
buttonOK.InnerRectangle.RadiusY = 5;
```

I want it all in code, no XAML, because I have many buttons in different XAML files and I want to round their edges by calling one method in code without changing every single XAML file. Not all buttons in all my XAML files, just certain ones.

I'm already calling a single method in all my windows and user controls and I just want to add the button rounding edges styling to that method, and then it won't cause tedious code.

Comment: What is the reason you want this in code, not in XAML?

Comment: @dymanoid

I have many buttons in different XAML's and I want to round their edges by calling a method in code without changing every single XAML file

Comment: Then you should create a `RoundedButtonStyle` in a resource dictionary and apply it to the buttons you want to change. I can't find a real reason to do it in code behind

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but this question: 'Set a property of a nested element in an WPF style' was not helpful to me. I found / made a solution which works for me and I can do it by just adding code. @JuanCarlosRodriguez

Comment: I didn't find an appropriate close reason, but if OP wants to self answer with how to do it by a deprecated method, I feel like letting him answer, then voting to close.

Comment: It's clearly a duplicate, the OP has just implemented a dynamic approach as per point 2. in the accepted answer on the duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set a property of a nested element in an WPF style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40657840/set-a-property-of-a-nested-element-in-an-wpf-style)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Load XAML from a string to a `Style` object that allows to change the corner radius in code and then set the button style.

This is the code that worked for me:

```
        // OK
        private void buttonOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SetButtonCornerRadiusAndTriggerStyling(buttonOK, 5);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error at 'buttonOK_Click'" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }

        // Set button corner radius and trigger styling
        public static void SetButtonCornerRadiusAndTriggerStyling(
            Button toStyle, int theCornerRadius,
            string theMouseOverBackground = "", string theMouseOverBorderBrush = "", string theMouseOverForeground = "",
            string thePressedBackground = "", string thePressedBorderBrush = "", string thePressedForeground = "",
            string theDisabledBackground = "", string theDisabledBorderBrush = "", string theDisabledForeground = "")
        {
            try
            {
                // Corner radius
                int cornerRadius = theCornerRadius;

                // Mouse over
                string defaultMouseOverBackground = "#BEE6FD";
                string defaultMouseOverBorderBrush = "#3C7FB1";
                string defaultMouseOverForeground = "Black";

                string mouseOverBackground = theMouseOverBackground;
                string mouseOverBorderBrush = theMouseOverBorderBrush;
                string mouseOverForeground = theMouseOverForeground;

                if (mouseOverBackground == null) { mouseOverBackground = ""; }
                if (mouseOverBorderBrush == null) { mouseOverBorderBrush = ""; }
                if (mouseOverForeground == null) { mouseOverForeground = ""; }

                if (mouseOverBackground.Length == 0) { mouseOverBackground = defaultMouseOverBackground; }
                if (mouseOverBorderBrush.Length == 0) { mouseOverBorderBrush = defaultMouseOverBorderBrush; }
                if (mouseOverForeground.Length == 0) { mouseOverForeground = defaultMouseOverForeground; }

                // Pressed
                string defaultPressedBackground = "#C4E5F6";
                string defaultPressedBorderBrush = "#2C628B";
                string defaultPressedForeground = "Black";

                string pressedBackground = thePressedBackground;
                string pressedBorderBrush = thePressedBorderBrush;
                string pressedForeground = thePressedForeground;

                if (pressedBackground == null) { pressedBackground = ""; }
                if (pressedBorderBrush == null) { pressedBorderBrush = ""; }
                if (pressedForeground == null) { pressedForeground = ""; }

                if (pressedBackground.Length == 0) { pressedBackground = defaultPressedBackground; }
                if (pressedBorderBrush.Length == 0) { pressedBorderBrush = defaultPressedBorderBrush; }
                if (pressedForeground.Length == 0) { pressedForeground = defaultPressedForeground; }

                // Disabled
                string defaultDisabledBackground = "#F4F4F4";
                string defaultDisabledBorderBrush = "#ADB2B5";
                string defaultDisabledForeground = "#83838C";

                string disabledBackground = theDisabledBackground;
                string disabledBorderBrush = theDisabledBorderBrush;
                string disabledForeground = theDisabledForeground;

                if (disabledBackground == null) { disabledBackground = ""; }
                if (disabledBorderBrush == null) { disabledBorderBrush = ""; }
                if (disabledForeground == null) { disabledForeground = ""; }

                if (disabledBackground.Length == 0) { disabledBackground = defaultDisabledBackground; }
                if (disabledBorderBrush.Length == 0) { disabledBorderBrush = defaultDisabledBorderBrush; }
                if (disabledForeground.Length == 0) { disabledForeground = defaultDisabledForeground; }

                string mainButtonStyleXAML = @"<Style xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' TargetType=""Button"">


    <Setter Property=""Template"">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType=""ButtonBase"">
                <Border
                    BorderThickness=""{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}""
                    BorderBrush=""{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}""
                    Background=""{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}""
                    Name=""BorderMain""
                    CornerRadius=""{CornerRadius}""
                    SnapsToDevicePixels=""True"">

                    <ContentPresenter
                        RecognizesAccessKey=""True""
                        Content=""{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}""
                        ContentTemplate=""{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}""
                        ContentStringFormat=""{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}""
                        Name=""ContentPresenterMain""
                        Margin=""{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}""
                        HorizontalAlignment=""{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}""
                        VerticalAlignment=""{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}""
                        SnapsToDevicePixels=""{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}""
                        Focusable=""False"" />
                </Border>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                <!-- Default -->
                <Trigger Property=""Button.IsDefaulted"" Value=""True"">
                    <Setter Property=""Border.BorderBrush"" TargetName=""BorderMain"">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DynamicResource
                                ResourceKey=""{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>

                <!-- Mouse Over -->
                <Trigger Property=""UIElement.IsMouseOver"" Value=""True"">
                    <Setter Property=""Panel.Background"" TargetName=""BorderMain"">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush>{MouseOverBackground}</SolidColorBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property=""Border.BorderBrush"" TargetName=""BorderMain"">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush>{MouseOverBorderBrush}</SolidColorBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property=""TextElement.Foreground"" TargetName=""ContentPresenterMain"">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush>{MouseOverForeground}</SolidColorBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>

                <!-- Pressed -->
                <Trigger Property=""ButtonBase.IsPressed"" Value=""True"">
                    <Setter Property=""Panel.Background"" TargetName=""BorderMain"">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush>{PressedBackground}</SolidColorBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property=""Border.BorderBrush"" TargetName=""BorderMain"">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush>{PressedBorderBrush}</SolidColorBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property=""TextElement.Foreground"" TargetName=""ContentPresenterMain"">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush>{PressedForeground}</SolidColorBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>

                <!-- Disabled -->
                <Trigger Property=""UIElement.IsEnabled"" Value=""False"">
                    <Setter Property=""Panel.Background"" TargetName=""BorderMain"">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush>{DisabledBackground}</SolidColorBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property=""Border.BorderBrush"" TargetName=""BorderMain"">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush>{DisabledBorderBrush}</SolidColorBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property=""TextElement.Foreground"" TargetName=""ContentPresenterMain"">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush>{DisabledForeground}</SolidColorBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>

            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

</Style>";



                // Replace values
                mainButtonStyleXAML = mainButtonStyleXAML.Replace("{CornerRadius}", cornerRadius.ToString());

                mainButtonStyleXAML = mainButtonStyleXAML.Replace("{MouseOverBackground}", mouseOverBackground);
                mainButtonStyleXAML = mainButtonStyleXAML.Replace("{MouseOverBorderBrush}", mouseOverBorderBrush);
                mainButtonStyleXAML = mainButtonStyleXAML.Replace("{MouseOverForeground}", mouseOverForeground);

                mainButtonStyleXAML = mainButtonStyleXAML.Replace("{PressedBackground}", pressedBackground);
                mainButtonStyleXAML = mainButtonStyleXAML.Replace("{PressedBorderBrush}", pressedBorderBrush);
                mainButtonStyleXAML = mainButtonStyleXAML.Replace("{PressedForeground}", pressedForeground);

                mainButtonStyleXAML = mainButtonStyleXAML.Replace("{DisabledBackground}", disabledBackground);
                mainButtonStyleXAML = mainButtonStyleXAML.Replace("{DisabledBorderBrush}", disabledBorderBrush);
                mainButtonStyleXAML = mainButtonStyleXAML.Replace("{DisabledForeground}", disabledForeground);

                StringReader mainButtonStyleXAMLStringReader = new StringReader(mainButtonStyleXAML);
                XmlReader mainButtonStyleXAMLXMLReader = XmlReader.Create(mainButtonStyleXAMLStringReader);
                Style mainButtonStyle = (Style)XamlReader.Load(mainButtonStyleXAMLXMLReader);

                toStyle.Style = mainButtonStyle;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(
                    "Error at 'SetButtonCornerRadiusAndTriggerStyling'" +
                        Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
                        ex.Message,
                    "Error",
                    MessageBoxButton.OK,
                    MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
```

So I had to put XAML in code, because FrameworkElementFactory is apparently deprecated.

MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory(v=vs.110).aspx

Under remarks:

> "This class is a deprecated way to programmatically create templates,
>   which are subclasses of FrameworkTemplate such as ControlTemplate or
>   DataTemplate; not all of the template functionality is available when
>   you create a template using this class. **The recommended way to
>   programmatically create a template is to load XAML from a string or a
>   memory stream using the Load method of the XamlReader class.**"

Comment: Instead of using empty default parameters and manually assign them, why don't you just use your default values as parameters? You can then remove all that checking