# How to access element (Image) from ControlTemplate defined in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates

1) Copy and paste the following code into MainWindow.xaml file.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ContextMenuStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border Background="MediumPurple" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="MediumPurple" CornerRadius="5">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Button Margin="3,3,3,3" Height="26" Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut">
                                <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150">
                                    <Image x:Name="Image1" Height="20" Width="30"/>
                                    <TextBlock Margin="5,2,5,0" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Wingdings 2" Text="&amp;"/>
                                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Cut"/>
                                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,5,0" Text="Ctrl+X"/>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Height="50" Width="300">
            <TextBox.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu Style="{StaticResource ContextMenuStyle}"/>
            </TextBox.ContextMenu>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

2) Copy and paste the following code into MainWindow.xaml.cs file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Image1.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Convert.FromBase64String("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")), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
        }        
    }
}
```

3. This is the error message:

> The name 'Image1' does not exist in the current context

4. This is the error picture:

[image: Picture]

So, how to access Image1 element from xaml control template?

Comment: How would you expect this approach to work with more than one such ContextMenu? You would usually avoid to access UI elements from code. Instead, bind the Image's Source property to a view model property, i.e. to a property of an object in the DataContext of your view.

Comment: Start reading here: [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview), and search the web for "wpf mvvm".

Comment: @Clemens, the issure likely doesn't require MVVM, because it just customization of a view, which done in the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templates (ControlTemplate, DataTemplate) are expected to be used to create multiple copies of the same layout. Those copies may be parametrized via Bindings or resources.

To set Source for Image inside template, you can use

1) a DynamicResource

changes in xaml:

```
<Image x:Name="Image1" Height="20" Width="30" Source="{DynamicResource MyPicture}"/>
```

code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow: Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        var img = BitmapFrame.Create(new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Convert.FromBase64String("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")), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
        this.Resources["MyPicture"] = img;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

2) Binding

changes in xaml:

```
<Image x:Name="Image1" Height="20" Width="30" Source="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
```

code-behind (`txt` is a `Name` assigned to TextBox: `<TextBox Height="50" Width="300" x:Name="txt">`)

```
public partial class MainWindow: Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var img = BitmapFrame.Create(new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Convert.FromBase64String("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")), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
        txt.Tag = img;
    }
}
```

Using Tag is a quick-and-dirty solution. When I need to custiomize templates, I prefer to create specialized Attached Dependency Properties - see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40663219/1506454) for details

Answer (score 0):

if the real problem is "how to set Image.Source from base64 string", then it is possible to do with a value converter, without code behind:

converter:

```
public class Base64ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            return BitmapFrame.Create(new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Convert.FromBase64String((string)value)), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

template:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Base64ImageConverter x:Key="imageConverter"/>

    <system:String x:Key="imageLetter">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</system:String>

    <Style x:Key="ContextMenuStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
                    <Border Background="MediumPurple" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="MediumPurple" CornerRadius="5">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Button Margin="3,3,3,3" Height="26" Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut">
                                <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150">
                                    <Image x:Name="Image1" Height="20" Width="30" Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource imageLetter}, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Margin="5,2,5,0" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Wingdings 2" Text="&amp;"/>
                                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Cut"/>
                                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,5,0" Text="Ctrl+X"/>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Source is set like this (using converter and base64 string, both defined in Resources):

```
Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource imageLetter}, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}"
```